# Image that has been resized is flickering on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an image that is about 400px by 300px in size.

I have resized it using css like so:

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

But when it displays it flickers constantly.

This only happens in Firefox. Chrome, IE and Safari all display fine. Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried using width and height instead of max-width and max-height?

Comment: It's because you are resizing big image to very tiny space. Better resize image via PHP or some desctop tool like Photoshop

Comment: What Firefox version are you using? Try to update Firefox to the latest version and test again ...

Comment: @FlorinPop, I amd using `max-..` so that I can retain the image proportions

Comment: @daan.desmedt, I'm using Firefox 32

Comment: @Justinas, using Photoshop, I'm afraid, is impossible as the images are posted by users and as such are dynamic. I also don't want to have to save a resized image for every image that is posted as this would lead to disk space concerns on the server.

Comment: Try CSS -> width: 50px , height: auto ... Same problem?

Comment: @daan.desmedt, yup, same problem. But I can't use `height: auto` because if the image height is a lot greater than the width the image will take up too much `height` space.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its a bad idea to resize the image. When you need a 50x50 image why have a 400x300 image. You waste the users band-with by letting him download a 30Kb file when he can do it with 4Kb.

However, what you want is to scale the image.
CSS3 has new property called `ri` .

try this

```
img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
```

You can use media queries along with this.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    img.ri { max-width: 90% }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    img.ri { max-height: 90% }
}
```

Now you don't want to loose your aspect ratio, so try the css property

```
resize: none|both|horizontal|vertical|initial|inherit; /* any one of the options IE not supported*/
```

Look into this : http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design if you want to responsively scale images.